# Find Fit error 4P logistic

Tags: fitting

I am trying to fit a four parameter logistic curve to my data set. I have the estimated values for each coefficint, but it says the jacobian is not a matrix...

Here is my data:

```
xydata = {{1000,18},{750,65},{500,67},{200,101},{100,88},{50,91},{25,86},{0,92}}

model = (a1 - a2)/(1 + (x/x0)^p) + a2

FindFit[xydata, model, {{a1, 93}, {a2, -2}, {x0, 800}, {p, 4}}, x]
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Trying to find a non-integer power `p` with `FindFit` worries me. If I assign `p=4` and `FindFit` the rest it instantly finds good fits for the other three variables. If clear the assignment of `p` and use those better estimates to try to find all four variables then it doesn't complain about finding these, but I am still skeptical about using `FindFit` this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several (non-*Mathematica*) issues.  You only have 8 data points to estimate 5 parameters (`a1`, `a2`, `x0`, `p`, and the error variance).  The model is essentially overparameterized.

Changing the model to allow for `x = 0` and adding in `MaxIterations->1000` gets a "result":

```
xydata = {{1000, 18}, {750, 65}, {500, 67}, {200, 101}, {100, 88}, {50, 91}, {25, 86}, {0, 92}};
model = (a1 - a2)/(1 + If[x == 0, 0, (x/x0)^p]) + a2
ff = FindFit[xydata, model, {{a1, 93}, {a2, -2}, {x0, 800}, {p, 4}}, x, MaxIterations -> 1000]
(* {a1 -> 90.7083, a2 -> -4.19539*10^7, x0 -> 175708., p -> 2.57191} *)
```

This will give you an equation that will give a plausible fit.

However, you should avoid `FindFit` as it doesn't give you any diagnostics.  Use `NonlinearModelFit` instead:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[xydata, model, {{a1, 93}, {a2, -2}, {x0, 800}, {p, 4}}, x, MaxIterations -> 1000];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a1 -> 90.7083, a2 -> -4.19539*10^7, x0 -> 175708., p -> 2.57191} *)
```

Now you can look at some diagnostics:

```
(* Parameter correlation matrix *)
nlm["CorrelationMatrix"] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Parameter correlation matrix]

```
(* Rank of parameter covariance matrix *)
MatrixRank[nlm["CovarianceMatrix"]]
(* 2 *)
```

These diagnostics (and maybe the estimated values of `a2` and `x0`) suggest that you have an overparameterized model.  The result reasonably reproduces the data but you certainly shouldn't attempt to interpret the values of the parameters - either their absolute value or sign.

Solutions?  (1) Get more data if you can.  (2) Don't bet the farm on the results.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thanks!